# Paper.js - convert `paperscript` to `javascript`

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to change this `paperscript`:

```
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas-1">
tool.minDistance = 10;
tool.maxDistance = 45;

var path;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    path = new Path();
    path.fillColor = new Color({ hue: Math.random() * 360, saturation: 1, brightness: 1 });

    path.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var step = event.delta / 2;
    step.angle += 90;

    var top = event.middlePoint + step;
    var bottom = event.middlePoint - step;

    path.add(top);
    path.insert(0, bottom);
    path.smooth();
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    path.add(event.point);
    path.closed = true;
    path.smooth();
}
</script>
```

to a stand alone `javascript` like:

```
paper.install(window);


window.onload = function() {
paper.setup('myCanvas');

tool.minDistance = 10;
tool.maxDistance = 45;

var path;

function onMouseDown(event) {
    path = new Path();
    path.fillColor = {
        hue: Math.random() * 360,
        saturation: 1,
        brightness: 1
    };

    path.add(event.point);
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var step = event.delta / 2;
    step.angle += 90;

    var top = event.middlePoint + step;
    var bottom = event.middlePoint - step;

    path.add(top);
    path.insert(0, bottom);
    path.smooth();
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    path.add(event.point);
    path.closed = true;
    path.smooth();
}
}
```

it give me an error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'tool.minDistance =
>   10')

What is `tool` here? I understand that I might need to declare it before I can use it. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: tool is `undefined` ... try `var tool = {};` Not that `tool` seems to *DO* anything..

Comment: @Pogrindis tried that. Same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the global scope as outlined in the [documentation](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/) :

```
paper.install(window);
```

Then get on with global defs. :

```
window.onload = function() {
        // Get a reference to the canvas object
        paper.setup('myCanvas');
        // In your case create tools 
        var tool = new Tool();
        tool.minDistance = 10;
        tool.maxDistance = 45;
```

Then continue as usual, this will set up your tools.. More can be found [here](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/).

Incidentally you've actually already done this correctly for `Path()`, so the same applies to `Tool()`

Answer (score 0):

When I use Paper.js directly in javascript I prefer to create paper object this way:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas-line');
paper.setup(canvas);
// and then if you want to create some Paper.js object prefix it's name with paper
var myPath = new paper.Path();
```

If you want to use tool you need to decelerate it with new paper.Tool();
For example if you want to check whether path was clicked:

```
    var tool1 = new paper.Tool();

    var handle;
    var myPath;
    myPath.fullySelected = true;

    tool1.onMouseDown = function(event) {
        handle = null;
        // Do a hit test on path for handles:
        var hitResult = myPath.hitTest(event.point, {
            handles: true,
            fill: true,
            stroke: true,
            segments: true,
            tolerance: 2
        });

        if (hitResult) {
            if (hitResult.type == 'handle-in') {
                handle = hitResult.segment.handleIn;
            } else if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
                handle = hitResult.segment.point;
            } else if (hitResult.type == 'handle-out') {
                handle = hitResult.segment.handleOut;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can find more informations about tools in here http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/