# Can anyone help me convert this paperscript to javascript?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have this paperscript from paper.js and i would like it to be converted in javascript but i cant get the mouse drag to work.

PaperScript recognises a couple of special event handlers when they are declared as global functions, while in JavaScript, these need to be manually installed on the appropriate object.

[Codepen of the paperscript](https://codepen.io/pexproduction/pen/KGxWQw?editors=1000)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-full.js"></script>
<!-- Define inlined PaperScript associate it with myCanvas -->
<script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">

var rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), new Point(150, 100));
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
  path.strokeColor = 'black';
  path.strokeWidth = 2;
path.selected = true;
  path.closed = true;


var hitOptions = {
    segments: true,
    stroke: true,
    fill: true,
    tolerance: 8
};



var segment, path;
var movePath = false;
function onMouseDown(event) {
    segment = path = null;
    var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
    if (!hitResult)
        return;

    if (event.modifiers.shift) {
        if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
            hitResult.segment.remove();
        };
        return;
    }

    if (hitResult) {
        path = hitResult.item;
        if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
            segment = hitResult.segment;
        } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') {
            var location = hitResult.location;
            segment = path.insert(location.index + 1, event.point);
            //path.smooth();
        }
    }
    movePath = hitResult.type == 'fill';
    if (movePath)
        project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    project.activeLayer.selected = false;
    if (event.item)
        event.item.selected = true;
}

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    if (segment) {
        segment.point += event.delta;
        //path.smooth();
    } else if (path) {
        path.position += event.delta;
    }
}


</script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" resize></canvas>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you changed anything on that code pen, but it looks like the mouseDrag events are working.  I can drag and move the box, I can also drag and move the corners separately, and add a new vertex by clicking a line and dragging it.

Comment: yes this works but it is a paperscript, i need it to work as javascript,
right now i have to use this: <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="myCanvas">

Comment: ah, I see, I missed the type definition.  I found this while looking into paperscript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498580/paper-js-convert-paperscript-to-javascript  I was able to move past the first "Rectangle is not defined" error, with the first two answers - but they also linked to some documentation which might help.  Sorry I can't give you a full answer, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differences between `PaperScript` and `JavaScript` contexts are detailled [here](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/).
In order to make the less changes possible to your code, you have to:

- [Install](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#install-scope) `Paper.js` in global scope. This allow you to use classes like `Path`, `Point`, ... directly (without passing trough global `paper` object).
- [Setup](http://paperjs.org/reference/paperscope/#setup-element) `Paper.js` to use your canvas. This is equivalent to setting the `PaperScript` `canvas` attribute.
- Create a [Tool](http://paperjs.org/reference/tool/) instance that you will use to register your event handlers.
- Use math operator functions (like [Point.add()](http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#add-number)) instead of operators (like `+`) when manipulating points.

Here is your code working in `JavaScript` context.

```js
// expose paperjs classes into global scope
paper.install(window);

// bind paper to the canvas
paper.setup('canvas');

var rectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 50), new Point(150, 100));
var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
path.fillColor = '#e9e9ff';
path.strokeColor = 'black';
path.strokeWidth = 2;
path.selected = true;
path.closed = true;


var hitOptions = {
  segments: true,
  stroke: true,
  fill: true,
  tolerance: 8
};


var segment, path;
var movePath = false;

// create a custom tool
var customTool = new Tool();

// attach handlers to the tool
customTool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
  segment = path = null;
  var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
  if (!hitResult) {
    return;
  }

  if (event.modifiers.shift) {
    if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
      hitResult.segment.remove();
    }
    return;
  }

  if (hitResult) {
    path = hitResult.item;
    if (hitResult.type == 'segment') {
      segment = hitResult.segment;
    } else if (hitResult.type == 'stroke') {
      var location = hitResult.location;
      segment = path.insert(location.index + 1, event.point);
      //path.smooth();
    }
  }
  movePath = hitResult.type == 'fill';
  if (movePath) {
    project.activeLayer.addChild(hitResult.item);
  }
};
customTool.onMouseMove = function(event) {
  project.activeLayer.selected = false;
  if (event.item) {
    event.item.selected = true;
  }
};
customTool.onMouseDrag = function(event) {
  if (segment) {
    // use methods instead of operators
    segment.point = segment.point.add(event.delta);
    //path.smooth();
  } else if (path) {
    path.position = path.position.add(event.delta);
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

canvas[resize] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for pointing out the last point with math operator functions. 
This is even missing from : http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/ which is really bad, because this is not trivial to debug as there are no errors... Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot sasensi ! As Kovács Ede pointed out math operator functions is difficult to find. In almost all frontend frameworks we need to use them the ways you has suggested & it is nowhere in the documentation!!!